# Can I use Inline Powershell in Build Script?

Tags: build, azure-devops, yaml

I need to build an Electron app installer with some "dynamic" values in the package.json. I'd like to replace a placeholder with powershell as part of the build process.

Can I use powershell inside this yml definition to set string to value1, build/publish artifact and then repeat using value2?

I can only find one example and it's calling an external script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I found it as soon as I posted!

steps:

- powershell: |

```
  Write-Host "This works!"
```